# Angular 2 kendo grid columns add custom class based on condiation

Tags: angular, frontend

I am using telerik kendo grid for angular 2. I need to set custom class to columns based on a condition. 
Example:

`<kendo-grid-column field="title" title="Title" [class.required]="isRequired"></kendo-grid-column>`

The problem is that even that **"isRequired"** property is **true** it does not set the class **"required"** to the column. What i know and i read is that to set a class **based on a condition** it is done with the following way: setting attribute **[class.required]="isRequired"** on the tag. But when i use it on the kendo-grid-column it is **not working**.

How to do it on **kendo-grid-column**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming isRequired is a variable within your component you can do this:

```
[class]="{'required': isRequired}"
```